# Why can't my discord.py bot see messages?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord.py bot and it does not "see" messages at all, it is supposed to print everything into the terminal and have a prefix, but it doesn't even print any message.
code:

```
import datetime
import os
import discord
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

TOKEN = ('boop')


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

async def on_message(message):
    print(f'USER - {message.author} texted - {message.content}')



@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("you have started")
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name= {message.author} + "w")



client.run(TOKEN)
```

(there are extra unused modules I'm planning to use later)

Comment: You need the message content intent. See: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents

Comment: I have every intent turned on in the Developer Portal

Comment: But not in the code. do `discord.Intents.all()` to enable every intent in the code

Comment: I have added intents = discord.Intents.all() into the code but still nothing

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code:

- You should only have one `commands.Bot` instance, events are not exclusive to `discord.Client`.
- For your bot to catch commands, you need `bot.process_commands` at the end of your `on_message` event.
- You were missing `@bot.event` above `on_message`.
- You forgot the fstring in `ctx.guild.create_role(...)`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os
import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from timeit import default_timer as timer

load_dotenv()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'USER - {message.author} texted - {message.content}')
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("You have started")
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name=f"{message.author}w")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```